# Rename txt file name in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a problem. I have created a few files txt in directory.

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

Next I writing name files to file txt: filenames.txt with step: Shell.

```
ls D:\test\prep\ > filename.txt
```

I have there all name files which are in directory. My filenames.txt looks like this:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

Later I read the values from the file in step Text file input and value which I get I writing to step copy to result.

[image]

Next I use get rows from result and transformation_executor.

[image]

I would like get a new name file for each file with step get rows from result: instead file1.txt I want file.txt. I think that in transformation_executor I must have TABLE_INPUT with name with step get rows from result but I don't know what's next.
Any have idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use below step/way, if you want to read a directory files based on another configuration file (which contain the directory files information).

Step-1:
[image]
Step-2:
[image]
Step-3:
[image]

You can found the all transformation/Job from [HERE](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1u4T-PSa2ylEJPf4XgWJWGDjfgkcg4CEA?usp=sharing)

Please let me know if its ok with you.

Comment: In GetEachFile_one_by_one I get:Couldn't open file #0 : file:///D:/pentaho/TestCase/Readdirectory --> org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileNotFoundException: Could not read from "file:///D:/pentaho/TestCase/Readdirectory" because it is not a file.

Comment: Ok, can you please share your transformation. I need to check.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1sPC7AHtCmDrJ9tH4t9UrRwodTjipKKAj?usp=sharing

Comment: You have missed to put .ktr extension [readDirectoryFile.ktr] in your 'filename_one_by_one' job  . Also missed in 'job1' [readFilename.ktr].  Please look your transformation location path in "transformation executor" step.

Comment: the paths to the transformations are correct

Comment: Ok, I have updated your ktr transformation path. Please get the updated files from https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1knvX3HdjKm5Ds7tNwBWaOhp2rUGikl3a?usp=sharing